# Conjugaison d'un verbe après "si" précédé par le conditionnel

Tags: expressions, conjugaison

Dans la phrase suivante:

> "Je voudrais savoir si je (**être**) concerné?".

Comment conjuguer l'auxiliaire "être"? Est ce que je peux utiliser le présent indicatif?

Par exemple:
"Je voudrais savoir si je suis concerné?" est-elle correcte?

Merci pour votre aide.

Comment: Si l'on parle du présent, oui l'indicatif présent est correct dans ce cas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tout dépend de la question que sous-entend la phrase.

- « Suis-je concerné ? » donne : « Je voudrais savoir si je suis concerné. »
- « Serais-je concerné ? » donne : « Je voudrais savoir si je serais concerné. »
- « Serai-je concerné ? » donne : « Je voudrais savoir si je serai concerné. »

On sent mieux la différence entre le futur et le conditionnel avec *nous* :

- « Serions-nous concernés ? » donne : « Je voudrais savoir si nous serions concernés. »
- « Serons-nous concernés ? » donne : « Je voudrais savoir si nous serons concernés. »

Comment: La première forme (verbe-sujet ...) est-elle formelle? peut-on l'utiliser à l'oral?

Comment: @IamNotaMathematician  L'inversion du verbe et du sujet est peu employée à l'oral.  Je l'utilise ici à des fins d'explication.  On dira plutôt dans le français parlé : " Est-ce que je suis concerné ? " ou bien " Je suis concerné ? " avec l'intonation propre à l'interrogation.